# How to fix short event rendering in thunderbird lightning

Tags: thunderbird, arch-linux, lightning

When I add multiple 15 minute events in the same hour to lightning, it renders them as if the are overlapping (see image). On another pc, this isn't a problem (the events are the full column size)

[image: Multiple 15 minute events in same hour]

Is there a way to fix this?

*Edit:*

It appears to be dependent on the screen resolution. On a different screen, the events are rendered correctly.

Comment: This also happens with Windows 7.  Is there any other solution besides changing resolution?

Comment: @FlorianJenn I noticed that zooming in / zooming out also has influence on this.

Comment: Sadly, no effect here (Windows 7, Thunderbird 17.0.6, Lightning 1.9.1).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the zooming factor (CTRL+/-) of the view i.e. the number of hours displayed in the view, but arises when the height of the events is the minimum value.
The minimum height depends on the text font size and a bit of margin/padding in the event boxes (the minimum height allows to vertically display the text). 
If you set a duration to 5 minutes for every event, you get the same problem if the zoom is too little.

To avoid the problem you have to increase the zoom factor, or you can add some css code in the userChrome.css file in order to reduce the minimum height of the boxes. Without changing the font size, you can try something like:

```
.calendar-event-box-container {
    margin: 0px !important;
}
```

but obviously the problem arises again if the zoom factor is too little.